# matplotlib legend picking with pandas dataframe doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, interactive, line-plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>>  60.1   65.5    67.3    74.2    88.5 ... 
A1   0.45   0.12    0.66    0.76    0.22
B4   0.22   0.24    0.12    0.56    0.34
B7   0.12   0.47    0.93    0.65    0.21
...
```

i'm trying to create line plot and to be able to enable/ disable some lines (like to display or hide certain items from the legend). I have found [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/legend_picking.html) . here the example is with numpy and not with pandas dataframe. When I try to apply it on my pandas df I manage to create plot but is not interactive:

```
%matplotlib notebook
def on_pick(event):
    # On the pick event, find the original line corresponding to the legend
    # proxy line, and toggle its visibility.
    legline = event.artist
    origline = lined[legline]
    visible = not origline.get_visible()
    origline.set_visible(visible)
    # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
    # have been toggled.
    legline.set_alpha(1.0 if visible else 0.2)
    fig.canvas.draw()
test.T.plot()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I get plot but **can't click on the legend items and display or hide them.**

My end goal: to be able to display or hide lines interactively from legend using the on_pick function from matplotlib.

edit: I understand that I have problem with this part of the documentation:

```
lines = [line1, line2]
lined = {}  # Will map legend lines to original lines.
for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
    legline.set_picker(True)  # Enable picking on the legend line.
    lined[legline] = origline
```

as I see that here the lines are taken "one by one" ut in my script I use pandas and T in order to get each line. not sure how to deall with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to extract all line2D objects on the figure. You can get them by using `ax.get_lines()`. Here the example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range("1/1/2000", periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=ts.index, columns=list("ABCD"))
df = df.cumsum()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax)
lines = ax.get_lines()
leg = ax.legend(fancybox=True, shadow=True)
lined = {}  # Will map legend lines to original lines.
for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
    legline.set_picker(True)  # Enable picking on the legend line.
    lined[legline] = origline

def on_pick(event):
    #On the pick event, find the original line corresponding to the legend
    #proxy line, and toggle its visibility.
    legline = event.artist
    origline = lined[legline]
    visible = not origline.get_visible()
    origline.set_visible(visible)
    #Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
    #have been toggled.
    legline.set_alpha(1.0 if visible else 0.2)
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.show()
```